# modx: rewriting a getResources query in a snippet

Tags: php, modx

I am fairly new to MODX and have been working on interfaces to talk to MODX.
Now I got the following query:

```
[[!getCache?
    &element=`getResources`
    &cacheExpires=`9000`
    &parents=`679,663,641,799,590`
    &depth=`0`
    &tpl=`related-article-in-page-listing`
    &limit=`6`
    &includeTVs=`0`
    &includeContent=`0`
    &showHidden=`1`
    &tvFilters=`Related Artist==[[*Related Artist]]`
    &toPlaceholder=`new`
    &resources=`-[[*id]]`
]]
```

that I would like to translate to a snippet so I can call it with the API via the runSnippet() method.

I've gotten this far:

```
<?php
$output = '';
$id = !empty($id) ? $id : 0;

$modx= new modX();
$modx->initialize('mgr');

$query = $modx->newQuery('modResource');
$query->where(array(
   'parent' => 679,
   'published' => 1,
   'Related Artists.value:=' => 603 // this will be replaced with $id when I get it to work...
));
$query->limit(5);
$titles = $modx->getCollection('modResource',$query);


foreach ($titles as $k) {
    $output.= '<li>'.$k->get('pagetitle').'</li>'; // let's just get the titles first
}

return '<ul>'.$output.'</ul>';
```

this will not return anything and I think I am just not clear as to what the above query actually calls in MySQL terms.
As var as I could tell it looks for entries that have either 679,663,641,799 or 590 as parent and the TV [[*Related Artist]] looks into a flied presumably called "Related Artist" for an exact match?!

Any help is appreciated here as I have been wrangling with the Book and online help for a couple days now ;)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

```
$query = $modx->newQuery('modResource');
$query->leftJoin('modTemplateVarResource', 'tv_value', 'tv_value.contentid = modResource.id');
$query->where(array(
    'modResource.parent:IN' => array(663,679,641,799,590),
    'modResource.published' => 1,
    'tv_value.tmplvarid' => 13,
    'tv_value.value' => $ID // this has been replaced with a dynamic $id but was "603" in my question
));
$query->limit(10);
$titles = $modx->getCollection('modResource',$query);
```

*(13 is the ID of my TV)*

So I now understand how the joins work in xPDO ;)
I hope this helps someone else some day

Comment: Glad you got it to work, but note that this does not answer your original question: "I got the following query... [getResources] that I would like to translate to a snippet so I can call it with the API via the runSnippet() method." Your answer has nothing to do with executing the `getResources` snippet.

Comment: As the title states: ```rewriting a getResources query in a snippet```. I may have gotten lost in the description though... sorry

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use runSnippet to execute getResources from within your own code, you can do this:

```
$id = $modx->getOption('id', $scriptProperties, $modx->resource->get('id'));
$related = $modx->getOption('related', $scriptProperties, ''); 

$params = array(
    'parents' => '679,663,641,799,590',
    'depth' => 0,
    'tpl' => 'related-article-in-page-listing',
    'limit' => 6,
    'includeTVs' => 0,
    'includeContent' => 0,
    'showHidden' => 1,
    'tvFilters' => "Related Artist==$related",
    'toPlaceholder' => 'new',
    'resources' => "-$id",
);
$output = $modx->runSnippet('getResources', $params);
```

Note that `$output` will be a string.

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/modX.runSnippet
http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Snippets

Comment: ah that makes so much more sense ... :) let me try it and get back to you

Comment: Hey. Sorry no it hasn't and I focused on this thread http://forums.modx.com/thread/85306/rewriting-a-getresource-query-into-a-snippet. I will update stackoverflow as soon as I have an answer.

Comment: Might need some adjustment, but it is the correct way to run a snippet using the API.

Answer (score 0):

Replace space in name(not title) of template variable `Related Artist` on "_", because it can be cause a various confusions.

Comment: Well spotted. It's not a good idea to have spaces in any element names - chunks and TVs included.